# forEach is not a function in lightning

Tags: jquery, salesforce-lightning

I am getting an error during the page load:

> forEach is not a function

Please advise if you have time. Thank you for the help.

```js
handleErrors: function(component, aErrors) {
  if (typeof aErrors === 'string') {
    var error = { message: aErrors };
    aErrors = [error];
  }

  var aComponentErrors = component.get('v.errors');
  aErrors.forEach(function(error) {
    if (error.message) {
      aComponentErrors.push(error.message)
    }

    if (error.pageErrors) {
      error.pageErrors.forEach(function(pageError) {
        aComponentErrors.push(pageError.message);
      });
    }

    if (error.fieldErrors) {
      error.fieldErrors.forEach(function(oError, fieldName) {
        oError.forEach(function(errorList) {
          aComponentErrors.push("Field Error on " + fieldName + " : " + errorList.message);
        });
      });
    }
  });
  component.set('v.errors', aComponentErrors);
},
```

Comment: Which line specifically is causing the error? The issue is because whatever variable you're calling `forEach()` on is not an array, so either `aErrors` or `error.fieldErrors`

Comment: One of oError, error.pageErrors ,error.fieldErrors or aErrors is not an array, so it does not have the forEach method... I'm certain you are getting more info in your error than just "forEach is not a function"

Comment: Be more specific about the error message. There are various positions in your code that could throw an error. `forEach` is a method of the `Array` prototype; the apparent naming convention in the code suggests that `oError` at least is _not_ a JS Array. Check with `typeof oError` and `Array.isArray(oError)`. And check on the other apparent array variables.

Comment: Thank you all for the reply. There is no documentations for this code. lightning page error out during page initialise. This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [aErrors.forEach is not a function] Failing descriptor: {markup://c:RateComponent}